# Error: 404 - COM_CONTENT_ERROR_PARENT_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

When I click on a Joomla article link it shows this error 'Error: 404 - COM_CONTENT_ERROR_PARENT_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND'. To be specified I have used 'mod_roksprocket' (Mosaic Layout) module to show a list of articles within a category. There are the 'read more' button to navigate through the articles details. Hence, clicking on this button triggered the describing error. I have searched a lot to get out of this riddle and everyone suggest for disabling the SEF url from Global Configuration. However, SEF url is a strict condition from my client.